# How to rename template folder in EE 2.9.2 ? (Free version)

Tags: templates, themes

Who know, how to rename template directory?
From /themes/site_themes/agile_records
To /themes/site_themes/*custom_name*

Comment: Don't be misled by the /themes/ nomenclature here. This is not a place to install a  site theme ala Wordpress. Most EE installs make no use of this directory.

Answer (score 2):

it is not really template directory - it is folder for template presets which use during install. After installation only images/js use from this folder. To change it you will need to make search  *agile_records* and replace  it with *custom_name* in DB or in files (before install).

Folder for saving template files, you can setup in

> CP Home -> Design -> Template Manager -> Global Template Preferences